# Render an iframe using formio

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, iframe, formio

I'm tring to make a new formio.js component to render iframes because i want something easy to show PDF files for example but the iframe does not work.
Everything is rendered except the iframe...
I did not succeed to use the html element neither.
Did someone aldready did this ?

Here's my view :

```html
<div>
    <p>{{ ctx.schema.title }}</p>
    <iframe
        src="https://files.form.io/pdf/5692b91fd1028f01000407e3/file/1ec0f8ee-6685-5d98-a847-26f67b67d6f0.html?id=elr4tq&amp;builder=1"
        id="iframe-elr4tq" seamless="true" class="formio-iframe"></iframe>
    <p>cc</p>
</div>
```

and the result :
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Whats the Style Properties of the ID and Class?

Comment: I took the example iframe of formio doc so the id and class styles are those on the files i imported. If i remove them it's the same. It's not the width or height because the iframe is not even on the "inspect" tab

Comment: Is your HTML Code inside some Framework? (e.g. Symfony, Laraval,...)

Comment: Nop, i developped my component using the webpack formio contrib and then i use the built version (.js and .css files) into my index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way to make it !
If someone is having the same trouble :

1)
Add a  with a ref attribute :

```html
<div>
    <p>{{ ctx.schema.title }}</p>
    <div ref="{{ ctx.key }}"></div>
</div>
```

2. Change the innerHTML within the attach function :

```js
  attach(element) {
    const refs = {};
    refs[this.component.key] = "pdf_div" // on recupere le ref="{{ ctx.key }}"

    this.loadRefs(element, refs); // Chargement de tous les refs

    this.div_pdf = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.refs[this.component.key], 0)[0]; // Return an array of matching refs (with [this.component.key])
    
    this.div_pdf.innerHTML = '<iframe src="" width="" height=""></iframe>' // Set the iframe to see the pdf

    // Allow basic component functionality to attach like field logic and tooltips.
    return super.attach(element);
  }
```